# Array - Object offset keep object rotation

Tags: modifiers

I'm making a 3 legged stool similar to this

[image]

I have positioned on leg and I want to position the next 2 using Array - Object offset. I have successfully achieved correct position of the legs however the rotation of the leg is incorrect.

[image]

The picture above shows bottom view of the stool. You can see that each leg is rotated differently. The correct one is the bottom leg. Is there an option how to "keep" the rotation of an object while using array?

Thank you.

Comment: this is weird because by default your legs should rotate around that empty as well, can you share your file to see your options?

Comment: Naming your legs left, right and bottom based on the positions on the picture, my guess is you applied the modifier to the vertical leg (otherwise unlikely to get exactly vertical), and rotated an empty so the bottom leg has correct transformation. This will never position the left (starting) leg correctly, and stacked transformations like on right leg will be incorrect. Try a setup with 5 or more legs to see it more clearly. You should instead have a simple setup, where you only rotate the empty by 120° around Z axis.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How you can do it - this way it works.

So you have something like this:

[image]

Note: the pivot point is at 0/0/0

No you can rotate the leg in object mode in x-axis like this:

[image]

Important: now press ctrl-a and apply rotation.

[image]

Then add an empty.

[image]

add an array modifier to your leg like this:

[image]

now select your empty and rotate by z-axis as you like.

[image]

you now still can correct the distance by selecting the leg again, press TAB to enter edit mode and press A to select all, then type G -> Y and move it as you like it.

[image]